# Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Product' not found

Tags: laravel, class

This is my ProductController

```
  public function eshop() {
      return Product::all();
      return view('eshop',compact('title'));
    }
```

then I have this

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Product extends Model
{
  //
}
```

I have this error Class `App\Http\Controllers\Product` not found
but I realy don't know how to solve this.

Comment: Your namespace must point to where the Product class is located, it cannot find it in App\Http\Controllers folder.

Answer (score 6):

You must tell your controller that it will use the Product model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Product;

class ProductController extends Controller
{
   //
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to reference you the namespace where your `Product` class is located.

Either put a references above your webcontroller class:

```
use App\Product;
```

Or use the full namespace name for the product in your code:

```
return \App\Product::all();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the `Product` class into your Controller as it is in a different namespace.

At the top of your Controller file add the line `use App\Product;`

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to solve this error.

1. add name space in your controller.
2. Calling model with exact location.

Example for first :

```
use App\Product;
```

add this line in your controller

Example for two :

```
\App\ModelName...i.e (\App\Product::all())
```

Answer (score 0):

use App\Models\Product; use this instead of use App\Product;